# Command line patch utility won't run under Big Sur

Tags: terminal, command-line, permission, big-sur

In trying to update `rsync` to v3.2.3 (pls do not tell me to use HomeBrew), I want to apply two patches before compiling. However, nothing happens under Big Sur when issuing the command: `patch -p1 patches/crtimes.diff`. I'm in the `rsync-3.2.3` folder, and patches is a folder under that. Adding `--verbose` does nothing, as it just hangs under Big Sur.
Under 'Security & Privacy' both `Terminal` and `/usr/bin/patch` have Full Disk Access.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

haha that's hilarious, the obvious was staring me in the face! Many thanks to @nohillside for pointing it out. It all works as intended :) patch takes input via the < which I missed many times.

```
patch -p1 < patches/crtimes.diff
```